# Pass an array in place of IList<string[]> in C#

Tags: c#, collections, method-parameters

In class below, I would like to sometimes pass just an array of strings for the property 'BodyParameters'.
Is that possible without using object type as its parameter type? Most times, this property will be a List of string [ ] arrays when the class is used.

```
public class EmailTemplate
{
    ...
    public IList<string[]> BodyParameters { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set `BodyParameters` using only a single `string[]`, you can do this:

```
string[] value = ...;
myEmailTemplate.BodyParameters = new [] { value };
```

There is no implicit conversion from `T` to `IList<T>`, where `T` is `string[]` in your case.

The above code will work because `new [] { ... }` will infer the type `string[][]`, which implements `IList<string[]>`.

Comment: Isn't T and IList<T>  representing different types, so some conversion would happen? I meant string[] and IList<string[]> are  different types so it would need conversion. But new[] {string[]} and IList<string[]> would be considered same by CLR which would not require conversion.

Comment: @Sunil `T[]` implements the interface `IList<T>`. When `T` is `string[]` that statement still holds: `string[][]` implements `IList<string[]>`.